# Is there any way I can execute this SPROC and get the result with Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2008

This SPROC "returns" a table with two columns: Id, Score.

Is it possible to execute this SPROC and include the custom data-type as parameters from within Entity Framework?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [presenta].[SearchLpi] 
    // The presenta.IdTableType is a table with just one column "Id"
    @selectedLpis presenta.IdTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH Scores AS(
        SELECT
            ItemId, SUM(Score) AS Score

        FROM [Presenta].[presenta].[LpivScores]

        WHERE
            ListPropertyItemId IN (
                SELECT Id
                FROM @selectedLpis
            )

        GROUP BY
            ItemId
    )
    SELECT
        i.Id,
        s.Score
    FROM
        Scores  s,
        Items   i
    WHERE
        s.ItemId = i.Id

END
```

If not, is there any other way to get the results of the SPROC and being able to join this result with another LINQ-query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are better of writing a EF linq query directly against the table. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896341.aspx for an example.

If you must use stored procedures, then there is a way using a table as a return type. You need to create a temporary table with the fields that you return. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/bindeshv/archive/2008/11/20/using-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the areas where EF 4 will bring a substantial improvement. With EF4, you'll be able to pull in a stored procedure, and if the return value of that sproc doesn't map to a given table, you can easily create a so-called complex type (basically a class) that will hold the stored proc return values.

See some blog posts for samples and more info on that:

- [Automatic Generation of Stored Procedure Return Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/automatic-generation-of-stored-procedure-return-types)
- [Using a Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 4](https://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/using-a-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-4)
- [A big step for Stored Procedures in EF4](https://web.archive.org/web/20131118015820/http://thedatafarm.com:80/blog/data-access/a-big-step-for-stored-procedures-in-ef4/)
- [Getting Started with Entity Framework 4 – Complex Types and Entities](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924084743/http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/11/24/getting-started-with-entity-framework-4-ndash-complex-types-and.aspx)

Yet another great new feature to look forward to!

Comment: EF4 is definitely worth looking forward to. However, right now I guess it wouldn't work very well in a corporate environment. Have to wait for the final release in March 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Create DefiningQuery in the Store part of the model with properties corresponding to the result of your stored procedure. 
You can make it using XML Editor you like. [Devart Entity Developer](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/) has design-time support for DefiningQueries.
Then create a function import for the procedure and set the return type to the hand-made  entity. 
Devart Team 
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect 
ADO.NET data providers for Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite with
Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL support